# 「見つかりません」v.s.「見つけません」

Tags: grammar, translation, verbs, tense

In my Japanese textbook, there’s a fill-in-the-blank question (and here I will modify it into a multiple-choice question for better comparison and contrast):

> さっきから携帯電話を探しているのですが、

A. 見つかりません。

B. 見つかりませんでした。

C. 見つけません。

D. 見つけませんでした。

I have two questions about this sentence: the first is about tense; the second is about 自動詞・他動詞。

I filled in 見つけませんでした and tried translating it into English (which is not my mother tongue either):

I’ve been looking for my mobile phone for a while, but didn’t find it (or couldn’t find it).

The answer given is 「見つかりません」.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

見つかる is intransitive, "to be found/located". 見つける is transitive, "to find/locate".

- A: 見つかりません = "it has not been found (so far / yet)."
- B: 見つかりませんでした = "it was not found."
- C: 見つけません = "I don't/won't find it."
- D: 見つけませんでした (= "I didn't find it.")

見つかる is the normal verb used when you talk about the result of a search in Japanese. We don't usually say C and D. For example "24 results found" is "24件見つかりました" in Japanese.

Between A and B, A is the better option because the first half of the sentence indicates this person is still trying to find the phone. B sounds like the speaker suddenly gave up in the middle of the sentence, which is a little unnatural.

Comment: I think your answer is correct from an "actual Japanese" perspective; but I have a vague feeling that, from a "textbook" perspective, they might have been aiming at C. Because A changes the sentence subject from "I" (am searching) to "cellphone" (isn't found), while C  keeps it as "I" (haven't found it).

In English, this would be a problem, but in Japanese it isn't; but I could easily imagine an English-native Japanese textbook writer expecting that to be the "best" answer for that specific reason.

Comment: Also, I really *hate* tests that have multiple acceptable answers, but have some vague reason why the one they've chosen is better than the others... especially when there might actually be some controversy. @Mathis, were there any guidelines in the quiz as to what they're looking for in terms of "most fitting" answer?

Comment: @MicahCowan 携帯電話を探しているのですが見つけません sounds terribly wrong. I can assure no native speaker would say this.

Comment: @MicahCowan In the textbook, the answer is A. I had the same feeling as you, and that's why I posted the question here.

Comment: @Mathis If you want to use 見つける, you can say 携帯電話を探しているのですが、(まだ)見つけられていません. See the potential form and the perfect aspect.

Comment: I had additional questions, and [asked them in a separate post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/77618/why-is-%e8%a6%8b%e3%81%a4%e3%81%91%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93-inappropriate-here).